# Race condition while receiving packets

Tags: list, sockets, networking, tcp, race-condition

I'm implementing the QUIC protocol in the Linux kernel. This is an alternative protocol to TCP.

QUIC works on a NACK based scheme where the ACK packet contains the highest received offset and selective NACKs for packets not received so far.

What happens is, when the kernel is processing an ACK packet and deleting the packets which have not been NACKed from the send queue, another ACK packet is received and interrupts this process. Processing of the new ACK packets deletes all the packets in the send queue which have not been NACKed.

So when the execution jumps back to the processing of the first ACK packet, I get a crash as the packet which was originally to be deleted has already been deleted by the new ACK interrupt and there is nothing there.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Either disable the interrupt while you're processing the packet queue, or don't process the packet queue for deletions in the receive ISR: do it in a timer ISR.

Comment: That's a good idea. But I would like to get rid of the acknowledged packets as soon as possible. What I'm using now is the `IS_ERR_OR_NULL()` function to ensure that I don't try dereferencing a dangling pointer and it works.